# Bluesnarfer in Backtrack 5

Tags: linux, arch-linux, backtrack

I'm new to backtrack and I am learning to hack Bluetooth . As you know I must use Bluesnarfer. But when I use it I get this error:

Can someone help me to solve this, I searched the Internet but I didn't find anything to solve it.

```
root@bt:~# bluesnarfer -r 1-100 -b 0:1A:16:A7:0C:77
bluesnarfer: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bluesnarfer isn't installed.

```
apt-get install bluesnarfer
```

should install it